# pattern match returns a different result for ArrayBuffer and Seq

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

In the sample below, there is a function `seqResult` that pattern matches against a `Seq`. Another function that accepts variable arguments calls `seqResult` and passes in an `ArrayBuffer`. This causes the pattern match result to be different when called with a `Seq` or with an `ArrayBuffer`.

With a `Seq` the matcher hits `case head :: rest => ...`, with an `ArrayBuffer` the matcher hits `case Seq(one, two) => ...`.

Is this a bug? Is there anyway to safeguard against this?

If it's not a bug, what is a safe way to match a list of 1 or more entries that would work for `Seq(a,b)` and `ArrayBuffer(a,b)`?

```scala
def seqResult(arr:Seq[String]) = arr match {
  case Nil =>  "Nil"
  case head :: Nil => "head :: Nil"
  case head :: rest => "head :: rest"
  case Seq(one, two) => "one, two"
  case _ => "other"
}

def varArgResult(args:String*) = seqResult(args)

val ab = varArgResult("one", "two")
val se = seqResult(Seq("one", "two"))

println(ab) //=> "one, two"
println(se) //=> "head :: rest"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::` is an extractor object for `List`s. Since lists are the default implementation of `Seq`, this is what you're seeing when you use `Seq(a, b, ...)`.

The extractor for `Seq`s is `+:`.

Comment: Cheers - what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`args: String*` is actually `Array`

`Seq()` constructor uses builder based on ListBuffer so as the result we have `List` data type.

```
object Seq extends SeqFactory[Seq] {
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = new mutable.ListBuffer
}
```

...

```
println(Seq("one", "two"))

List(one, two)
```

`head::rest` is syntax sugar for `List` matching and can be represented as `List(head, rest)` which is match `se` in your case.

Comment: just added a final question - what's the best match option in this case?